# Warnings when transforming to logarithmic scale, a lot of NaNs produced

Tags: r, mclust, factoextra

For a few weeks, I have used the following script to produce a scatterplot with approximately 10,000 (non-zero, positive) datapoints. Only few (<20) datapoints were not included because of warnings with the transformation.

```
visual <- ggplot(data=dots, aes(GRNHLin, REDHLin)) +
    geom_point(colour=rgb(0.17, 0.44, 0.71), size=0.500, alpha=0.250) +
    scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                  labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)), limits = c(1,1e4)) +
    scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                  labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)), limits = c(1,1e3))
visual
```

Since this week, I want to do some model-based clustering. The script I wrote (see below) uses the same dataset (10,000 non-zero, positive datapoints) but leaves out more than 9,000 datapoints because of:

```
Warning messages:
1: In self$trans$transform(x) : NaNs produced
2: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous x-axis 
3: In self$trans$transform(x) : NaNs produced
4: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis 
5: Removed 9692 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

This is the second script:

```
dots.Mclust <- Mclust(dots, modelNames="VVV", G=8)

visual <- fviz_cluster(dots.Mclust, 
             ellipse=FALSE, 
             shape=20, 
             geom = c("point")) +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)), limits = c(1,1e3)) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)), limits = c(1,1e4))
visual
```

**EDIT**

Some additional information:

The dataset contains only values that are larger than 0. Head(dots.Mclust) provides the following:

```
$data
           GRNHLin    RED2HLin
   [1,]   81.50364  176.379654
   [2,]   57.94751  116.310577
   [3,]   42.89310  119.758621
   [4,]   41.82213  275.607971
   [5,]  437.14648  141.309647
   [6,]   15.20952  177.128616
   [7,]   18.88731  257.249207
   [8,]  768.64935  172.374069
   [9,]   24.66220  118.283150
  [10,]   17.12160   68.955154
  [11,]   73.00019   71.517052
  [12,] 1182.08911  180.694122
  [13,]  320.09827  224.808563
  [14,]  268.42401  235.375259
  [15,]  149.05655  205.708282
  [16,]   98.43160  152.093704
  [17,]   25.10120  177.061386
  [18,]  293.87103  239.007050
  [19,]  118.42249  295.722168
  [20,]  724.16718  243.950455
  [21,]  255.26083  128.209717
  [22,]  105.15983  247.946701
  [23,]   86.25691  220.004745
  [24,]  122.01743   32.232780
  [25,]   50.42104    9.923141
```

The graph, after removing the scaling on the x-axis and y-axis, looks the following. Apparently, something goes wrong with the datapoints. There are no negative values in the dataset, but there are still (a lot of) points below 0. Furthermore, the x-axis and y-axis do not cover the values found in entry [12,]. This is probably the underlying cause of the problem. But how does this issue with wrong values occur?

[image: Graph after plotting (without scaling x-axis and y-axis).]

What is the underlying issue here?

Comment: Please share a handful of data points illustrating the problem - identify say 10 points that about half of them stay in and about half of them produce `NaN`s. Most likely you will solve your own problem as soon as you identify a sample of points causing the problem, but if not post that sample data and we will be able to help. But without data there's not much for us to work with and no way for us to test possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have provided additional information and found, probably, the underlying issue. It is, however, not clear to me how this underlying problem occurs.

Comment: You're making a bad assumption that the cluster visualization is on the same scale as the input data. I don't know these algorithms well enough to tell you what's going on, but likely the inputs are centered and rescaled. The plotted outputs are clearly on a different scale. I ran `Mclust` and plotted the result using just the 25 sample rows you provided. The sample data ranges from ~10 to ~1200, the output plot ranges from -2 to 3. If you don't understand what is being plotted, I'd suggest reading through the documentation of the clustering and plotting functions.

Comment: Thank you. When setting different limits for the axis, it appears that the shape of the scatterplot is equal to the shape that it has to have. In this way, I conclude that something with the axes is going wrong. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong except your expectations. I think some background reading on the clustering algorithms, how they work, and how they're presented will help you understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed correct, as mentioned in the comments, that the sample data are centered and rescaled. This option can be turned off via including

```
stand=FALSE,
```

in the options of fviz_cluster.